# dynamic select dropdown - no selected option

Tags: jquery, select, dropdown

I am trying to create a dynamic select;

Every time I create a user on the database table, it adds a `<td class="users">` to the markup: `<td class="users">name of the user extracted from the db</td>`

html

```
<select id="selectUser">
  <option selected disabled>Select a user...</option>
</select>
```

js

```
var names = {};
$('.users').each(function() {  
     names = $(this).html();
     printContent(names);
});

function printContent(content)
{
   $( '<option class="selectOption">' + content + '</option>' ).appendTo( "#selectUser" );

}
```

And it does display the user's name as I need, but, the select doesn't change the selected class. How can I add selected class to element it's being displayed?

I have added the code in http://jsfiddle.net/hh7r7p3w/. Just to mention, the real data with the user names comes from the database, so this name can variate.

Am I trying to do something I can't do in the way I'm trying?

Thank you

Comment: [`$('option:selected').prop('selected', false);`](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/hh7r7p3w/1/)

Comment: sorry..... where do I add this? within the function?

Comment: I've also added the updated fiddle, click on it. It is added in `printContent` function as the first statement

Answer (score 0):

You can add the option's property as

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var names = {};
  $('.users').each(function() {
    names = $(this).html();
    printContent(names);
  });

  function printContent(content) {
    $('option:selected').prop('selected', false);
    $('<option class="selectOption">' + content + '</option>').appendTo("#selectUser");
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="users">User 1</td>
    <td class="users">User 2</td>
    <td class="users">User 3</td>
    <td class="users">User 4</td>
    <td class="users">User 5</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<select id="selectUser">
  <option selected disabled>Select a user...</option>
</select>
```